# Pass an array as function input VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, input

After some trials and research, I can't manage to figure out how to pass an array as the input of a function.

This is my code:

```
Function read_coordinates()
'''This function reads the coordinates (X,Y) of the machines in the sheet !layout and stores them in an N*2 array

number_of_machines = Count_WT()

'I use an temporary array since I cannot manage to define well the array_read_coordinates.
ReDim WTG_coord(1 To number_of_machines, 1 To 2) As Double

For i = 1 To number_of_machines
    WTG_coord(i, 1) = Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Layout").Cells(5 + i, "H").Value
    WTG_coord(i, 2) = Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Layout").Cells(5 + i, "I").Value
Next

read_coordinates = WTG_coord
Set WTG_coor = Nothing
End Function
```

Now, I have another function, that I want to use to change the values of the coordinates after a rotation:

```
Function Rotate_coordinate(coord_system() As Variant, theta As Long)
''' This function determine the coordinates of the machines after a rotation of an angle of 270 - theta
'coord_system is the array of the initial coordinates of the machines
'theta is the angle of view

'We define the rotation matrix for the angle 270-theta
Dim M(1 To 2, 1 To 2) As Double
M(1, 1) = -Sin(theta)
M(1, 2) = Cos(theta)
M(2, 1) = -Cos(theta)
M(2, 2) = -Sin(theta)

x = UBound(coord_system, 1)          'We read the length of the matrix (ie  get the number of WTG)
Dim Rotate_coordinate(1 To x, 1 To 2)
For i = 1 To x
    Rotate_coordinate(i, 1) = M(1, 1) * coord_system(i, 1) + M(1, 2) *  coord_system(i, 2)
    Rotate_coordinate(i, 2) = M(2, 1) * coord_system(i, 1) + M(2, 2) * coord_system(i, 2)
Next

End Function
```

I want to use this function as a generic one since I will have to use it with multiple `coord_systems` later.

Thanks in advance for the advice!

Comment: I think you need `theta As Double` to use `Cos()` and `Sin()` properly. Also you need to convert from degrees to radians.

Comment: In your code you write into `Rotate_coordinate` but then you never use it outside of the function. Did you mean to write `coord_system=Rotate_coordinate` in the end?

Comment: See my answer on how to return an array from a function. Otherwise you need a `Sub()` to modify an existing array.

Comment: Yes, I intend to use these functions in a sub () at the end. I can't have access to my code right now, but I'll try your answer as soon as possible.

Comment: I meant you need `Sub Rotate_coordinate(ByRef coords() as Double)` if you want to update the contents of `coords()` instead of declaring a function.

Comment: This is a case where building a `CoordinateSystem` class would be beneficial. You can include all functions that manipulate the coordsys in the same file allowing you to do things like `pt = cs.LocalToWorld(local)` and re-use the same code over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

I am using standard right hand rotation in order to return a new rotated array based on the inputs:

```
Public Function RotateCoordinatesDegree(ByRef Coords() As Double, ByVal angle_deg As Double) As Double()
    Dim rot() As Double, cx As Double, sx As Double, x As Double
    Dim i As Long, N As Long
    N = UBound(Coords, 1)
    ReDim rot(1 To N, 1 to 2)
    x = WorksheetFunction.Radians(angle_deg)
    sx = Sin(x): cx = Cos(x)
    For i = 1 To N
        rot(i, 1) = Coords(i, 1) * cx - Coords(i, 2) * sx
        rot(i, 2) = Coords(i, 1) * sx + Coords(i, 2) * cx
    Next i
    RotateCoordinates = rot
End Function

Public Sub TestCoord()
    Dim cs1() As Double, cs2() As Double, theta, i As Long
    ReDim cs1(1 To 10, 1 To 2)
    For i = 1 To 10
        cs1(i, 1) = CDbl(i) / 10#: cs1(i, 2) = 1#
    Next i
    theta = 15
    cs2 = RotateCoordinatesDegree(cs1, 270 - theta)

End Sub
```

**Edit 1**

If you just want to modify the existing coordinates then try this

```
Public Sub RotateCoordinatesDegree(ByRef Coords() As Double, ByVal angle_deg As Double) 
    Dim cx As Double, sx As Double, ang As Double, x as Double, y as Double
    Dim i As Long, N As Long
    N = UBound(Coords, 1)
    ang = WorksheetFunction.Radians(angle_deg)
    sx = Sin(ang): cx = Cos(ang)
    For i = 1 To N
        x = Coords(i, 1) * cx - Coords(i, 2) * sx
        y = Coords(i, 1) * sx + Coords(i, 2) * cx
        Coords(i,1) = x : Coords(i,2) = y
    Next i
End Sub

Public Sub TestCoord()
    Dim cs1() As Double, theta, i As Long
    ReDim cs1(1 To 10, 1 To 2)
    For i = 1 To 10
        cs1(i, 1) = CDbl(i) / 10#: cs1(i, 2) = 1#
    Next i
    theta = 15
    RotateCoordinatesDegree cs1, 270 - theta

End Sub
```

Comment: I tested your code, but I still have problems that I can't explain. In your first code, in sub TestCoord(), I can't get the values of cs2.. For exemple , Debug.Print cs2(1,1) yields the error message : Error 9: subscript out of range.

Comment: If you can't explain we can't help you. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for some hints into how to explain your issue.

Comment: Another problem is that i can't manage to pipe instructions. for exemple, I use the first function to read the coordinates so I write `coord1 = read_coordinates() `. Then it doesn't work if I pass `coord1`as input of `RotateCoordinatesDegree`. Instead, I have to create a new array `coord2`, and copy the values of `coord2(i,j)=coord1(i,j)`to pass it as input of `RotateCoordinatesDegree`. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Please edit your question by _adding_ additional requirements and examples of what you want to do.

Comment: Like `cs = RotateCoordinatesDegree(cs, 270 - theta)` and then `cs = RotateCoordinatesDegree(cs, 270 - psi)` ? I really can't comment unless I see the code you have trouble with,

Answer (score -1):

You should use `ByRef` to pass an array in a function, sub or property.

Declaration:

```
Function MyFunction (ByRef MyArray() As long)
'Code goes here
End Function
```

Comment: `ByRef` is implied when not specified in VBA.